# OS X software for copying from Windows File Shares

Tags: software-recommendation, windows

I am migrating from Windows as my desktop operating system, but will still need to interact with Windows file servers.

Is there any OS X software to help with copying files from file servers.  I am specifically looking for an analogue of [Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) that will copy files from a directory on a Windows file server, and retry any files that fail.

I'm happy using either a GUI or command line.

Comment: Are you looking for an alternative to the OOB methods to do that?

Comment: I wasn't aware of an OOB box method that will do that with a Windows File Server.  I'd accept an answer that gave the OOB method.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the SAMBA protocol (or Apple's implementation of it), to connect to a Windows Share.

Either open **Finder** and choose "*Go*" -> "*Connect to Server*" in the menu bar.
[image: Example]

Now connect to your share(s) using the **SMB://** as protocol definition. If activated it will ask you for authentication afterwards. Then the share will be mounted like any other mount point.

Or you could use the terminal to mount the file system using the

```
mount_smbf
```

command.

After you've mounted the Windows Share you should be able to use any command line tool or GUI software do to your copying. Instead of robocopy you could use **rsync** for example (which is built in and pretty powerful).

One note: Just remember that saving files directly from within apps on a share could cause some troubles if they are using Apples's Versions feature, which is not supported by FAT or NTFS file systems.